# 'If' statement isn't working properly when I use the 'or' conditional statement

Tags: python-3.x

I want to change the format of a date (string). To achieve this, I'm trying to append each part of the date separately into the list `_list`. However, the code always evaluates the conditional to True, no matter what conditional statements I use (`or` in this case). Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

```py
string = '2021/Mar/14'
_list = []
aux = ""
for i in string:
    if i != '/' or i != ' ' or i != '.': #This is always true
        aux = aux + i
    else:
        _list.append(aux)
        aux = ""
print(_list)
```

Comment: Maybe you want `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: Ok now it's working, thaks you! Can you move you comment to an answer so I can mark as solved my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is by definition always `True` since any string is by definition unequal to at least two of three unequal strings. For an `or`-condition to be `True` it is sufficient if one of the parts is `True`. As Mark Ransom correctly pointed out in his comment, `and` is probably what you were aiming for.